# Problems with deserialize Json

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-boot, deserialization

Given the following json file:

```
{
  "noticiaDTOs": [
    {
      "idiomaPais": {
        "idioma": {
          "id": 3,
          "iso6391": "pt"
        },
        "pais": {
          "id": 1,
          "sigla": "BR"
        }
      },
      "linguagem": null,
      "defaultLanguage": 1,
      "idiomaNoticia": {
        "id": 114,
        "conteudo": "<p>uhuhuhuhuhu</p>",
        "titulo": "uhuhuhuhuhu",
        "resumo": "<p>huhuhuhuhu</p>"
      },
      "fileDTO": {
        "profileDTO": {
          "filetype": "application/json",
          "value": " O BASE 64 DA IMAGEM"
        },
        "nome": "pt-BR"
      },
      "tags": [
        {
          "dtCriacao": "2020-10-07T12:48:16.775+0000",
          "dtAlteracao": "2020-10-07T12:48:16.775+0000",
          "ativo": true,
          "id": 4,
          "nome": "Política",
          "tag": "POLI"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "idiomaPais": {
        "idioma": {
          "id": 4,
          "iso6391": "en"
        },
        "pais": {
          "id": 10,
          "sigla": "US"
        }
      },
      "linguagem": null,
      "defaultLanguage": 2,
      "idiomaNoticia": {
        "id": "",
        "conteudo": [],
        "titulo": [],
        "resumo": []
      },
      "fileDTO": {
        "profileDTO": {}
      },
      "tags": [
        {
          "dtCriacao": "2020-10-07T12:48:16.775+0000",
          "dtAlteracao": "2020-10-07T12:48:16.775+0000",
          "ativo": true,
          "id": 4,
          "nome": "Política",
          "tag": "POLI"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "idiomaPais": {
        "idioma": {
          "id": 5,
          "iso6391": "it"
        },
        "pais": {
          "id": 11,
          "sigla": "IT"
        }
      },
      "linguagem": null,
      "defaultLanguage": 2,
      "idiomaNoticia": {
        "id": "",
        "conteudo": [],
        "titulo": [],
        "resumo": []
      },
      "fileDTO": {
        "profileDTO": {}
      },
      "tags": [
        {
          "dtCriacao": "2020-10-07T12:48:16.775+0000",
          "dtAlteracao": "2020-10-07T12:48:16.775+0000",
          "ativo": true,
          "id": 4,
          "nome": "Política",
          "tag": "POLI"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "usuario": {
    "dtCriacao": "2020-04-27T20:14:53.748+0000",
    "dtAlteracao": "2020-10-23T16:19:32.809+0000",
    "ativo": true,
    "id": 39,
    "pessoa": {
      "dtCriacao": "2020-04-27T20:14:53.484+0000",
      "dtAlteracao": "2020-04-27T20:14:53.484+0000",
      "ativo": true,
      "nome": "Fenacon T.I",
      "nascimento": null,
      "inscricaoEstadual": null,
      "email": "tifenacon@gmail.com",
      "telefone": "321321321231",
      "celular": "2323123123123",
      "cnpj": "70899341000126",
      "razaoSocial": "Fenacon T.I",
      "idPessoa": 244
    },
    "perfilUsuario": {
      "dtCriacao": "2020-01-08T02:00:00.000+0000",
      "dtAlteracao": "2020-01-08T02:00:00.000+0000",
      "ativo": true,
      "id": 1,
      "nome": "Administrador",
      "perfil": "ADMINISTRADOR"
    },
    "senha": "$2a$10$RUSfuzwbWGGd/8jqh0Ltm.XrV8q3gdW8K7Dfg0/7HCWkKgLFZhafe",
    "logado": false,
    "primeiro_acesso": false
  },
  "tags": [
    {
      "dtCriacao": "2020-10-07T12:48:16.775+0000",
      "dtAlteracao": "2020-10-07T12:48:16.775+0000",
      "ativo": true,
      "id": 4,
      "nome": "Política",
      "tag": "POLI"
    }
  ]
}
```

i got this method for read this:

```
@PostMapping
    @RequestMapping("/update/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public List<NoticiaIdiomaDTO> update(@RequestBody NoticiaIdiomaDTO noticiaIdiomaDTO, @PathVariable("id")Long id) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        List<NoticiaIdiomaDTO> noticiasIdiomasDTO = new ArrayList<NoticiaIdiomaDTO>();
        try {
            Noticia noticia = new Noticia();
            List<NoticiaDTO> noticiaDTOs = noticiaIdiomaDTO.getNoticiaDTOs();
            String nameImage = new String();
            if (noticiaIdiomaDTO.getFileDTO() != null) {
                nameImage = uploadImage(noticiaIdiomaDTO.getFileDTO());
                //int i = 0;
            }
            int i = 0;
            for(NoticiaDTO noticiaDTO : noticiaDTOs) {
                if(noticia.getId() != null) {
                    if(noticiaDTO.getFileDTO()!=null && noticiaDTO.getFileDTO().getProfileDTO().getValue() != null) {
                        uploadFile(noticiaDTO.getFileDTO());
                        if(noticiaDTO.getDefaultLanguage() == 1) {
                            noticia.setThumbnail(nameImage);
                            //Pais pais = new Pais();
                            Optional<Pais> pais = paisService.porId(1);
                            //pais.setId(paisService.getByUsuario(noticiaIdiomaDTO.getUsuario().getId()).getId());
                            noticia.setPais(pais.get());
                            noticia.setId(null);
                            //noticia.setConteudo(noticiaIdiomaDTO.getNoticiaDTOs().get(0).getIdiomaNoticia().getConteudo());
                            //noticia.setTitulo(noticiaIdiomaDTO.getNoticiaDTOs().get(0).getIdiomaNoticia().getTitulo());
                            noticia.setUsuario(noticiaIdiomaDTO.getUsuario());
                            //noticia.setAtivo((noticia.getAtivo()) == false)?2:noticia.getAtivo());
                            //noticia.setUrl(EnvironmentsUtil.getEnvironmentImage());
                            service.atualizar(noticia);
                            NoticiaTAG noticiaTag = new NoticiaTAG();
                            noticiaTag.setNoticia(noticia);
                            noticiaTag.setTag(noticiaDTO.getTags().get(i));
                            noticiaTagService.atualizar(noticiaTag);
                            IdiomaNoticia idiomaNoticia = new IdiomaNoticia();
                            idiomaNoticia = noticiaDTO.getIdiomaNoticia();
                            idiomaNoticia.setNoticia(noticia);
                            idiomaNoticia.setIdioma(noticiaDTO.getIdiomaPais().getIdioma());
                            idiomaNoticiaService.atualizar(idiomaNoticia);
                        }
                    }
                    if(valid) {             
                        uploadFile(noticiaDTO.getFileDTO());
                    }
                };
                noticiasIdiomasDTO.get(i).setNoticiaDTOs(noticiaDTOs);
                i++;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            throw new AppException("Erro Interno no Servidor.");
        }
        return noticiasIdiomasDTO;
    }
```

but, i received this error:

2021-02-25 15:39:48.329  WARN 16204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 65973] (through reference chain: br.com.ifenacon.idbs.orm.model.custom.NoticiaIdiomaDTO["noticiaDTOs"]->java.util.ArrayList[1]->br.com.ifenacon.idbs.orm.model.custom.NoticiaDTO["idiomaNoticia"]->br.com.ifenacon.idbs.orm.model.IdiomaNoticia["conteudo"])]

Comment: Could you also include the code of NoticiaIdiomaDTO. That makes it a bit easier to understand to what object you are deserialising

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in the json you have provided conteudo has two types (a list and a String):

```
    "conteudo": [],
```

and

```
    "conteudo": "<p>uhuhuhuhuhu</p>",
```

This means it cannot be deserialized to String from a List. or vice Versa

This is likely a bad json file.  if it is not you can deserialize it to Object and then in the code use toString() and figure out if it should be a list and manually deserialize it from there, or just use it as a String

Answer (score 0):

The real error you have is

> Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY
> token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 65973]
> (through reference chain:
> br.com.ifenacon.idbs.orm.model.custom.NoticiaIdiomaDTO["**noticiaDTOs**"]->java.util.ArrayList[1]->br.com.ifenacon.idbs.orm.model.custom.NoticiaDTO["**idiomaNoticia**"]->br.com.ifenacon.idbs.orm.model.IdiomaNoticia["**conteudo**"])]

If you look at your JSON, this corresponds to

```
 "noticiaDTOs": [
    {
      "idiomaNoticia": {
        "conteudo": "<p>uhuhuhuhuhu</p>",
      }
    }
]
```

But you also have one of these

```
 "noticiaDTOs": [
    {
      "idiomaNoticia": {
         "conteudo": [],
      }
    }
]
```

You need to check your datamodel if you need a String or an Array here. (Given the error, I think you defined it as String) You cant use both for the same field. This indicates that the issue is your **JSON**, that is not correct. The Arrays need to be replaced by Strings (or your datamodel needs to be changed to use a List type + String item must be changed in the JSON)